# Issue with Alamofire Request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire to make a web request.  It had been working absolutely fine, but after doing a recent pod update it has stopped.

My syntax is:

```
    var params = [String : Any]()
    if (data != nil) {
        params = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String : Any]
    }

    let _ = Alamofire.request( "http://example.com" , method: Method, parameters: params?, encoding: .queryString, headers: [:]).response{ (request, response, data, error) in
    }
```

the error looks is  "Extra argument 'method' in call"  and I don't seem to be able to get rid of it.  My parameters of the request to Alamofire.request seem ok to me, but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: What is `.queryString` and what is `Method` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing anything to the `method` parameter. I don't know what you're trying to provide in the `encoding` parameter either but that went through some changes in Alamofire 4.0. For example and for simplicity's sake, this compiles:

```
let _ = Alamofire.request( "http://example.com" , method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```